# Value of property Event must be of type String in CloudFormation in TopicConfigurations for an S3 bucket

Tags: json, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs, aws-cloudformation

I have this code in the cloudformation template:

```
     "MyBucket": {
     "Type" : "AWS::S3::Bucket",
     "Properties" : {
     "NotificationConfiguration": {
              "TopicConfigurations": [
                {
                  "Event": ["s3:ObjectCreated:Put" , "s3:ObjectCreated:Post"], 
                  "Topic": { "Ref": "TopicSNS" }
                }
              ]
            }
}
}
```

After testing this code by creating a stack in CloudFormation, I get this error : `Value of property Event must be of type String` and the creation fails.
What is the raison of that?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a list to the `Event` property, but [`Event` requires a string value](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-notificationconfig-topicconfig.html#cfn-s3-bucket-notificationconfig-topicconfig-event).  To configure multiple Events, create multiple `TopicConfigurations` objects:

```
"MyBucket": {
  "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
  "Properties": {
    "NotificationConfiguration": {
      "TopicConfigurations": [
        {
          "Event": "s3:ObjectCreated:Put",
          "Topic": {
            "Ref": "TopicSNS"
          }
        },
        {
          "Event": "s3:ObjectCreated:Post",
          "Topic": {
            "Ref": "TopicSNS"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```